# Postgresql string array vs join for user management schema?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I am creating a database schema for user management in PostgreSQL. As, it supports array, so I am trying with three approaches.

Which one is best, querying with joins or getting/setting role data with array?

Considering large user base in near future.

**Approach 1:**

User table

```
id 
user_name
```

Role table

```
id 
role_name
```

RoleUser table

```
role_id 
user_id
```

**Approach 2**

User table

```
id
user_name
[integer array of role id]
```

Role

```
id 
role_name
```

**Approach 3**

User table

```
id
user_name
[string array of role key]
```

Role

```
id 
role_name
role_key
```

Comment: The first.  Only the first.

Comment: But, in 2 & 3 approach, I can save join while authorizing user. So, isn't it good?

Comment: Why do you want to save a join?  Wait, you don't.  Try to measure the performance difference of both approaches.  Just add a bunch of fake users, and measure.

Comment: You are using a *relational* DBMS and you are thinking about saving a join? That makes no sense. Such products are *expected* to work with joins efficiently. That's part of their job. Your Approach 1 is *the* way to implement a many-to-many relationship in an RDBMS – *if* you want to go the relational road, that is.

Comment: The basic storage is cleanest in approach 1. Implementation basics: [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9790225/939860)  For special purposes or display, you can always add a (materialized) view, aggregating arrays or strings like in approach 2 or 3.